# systemctl / journal distinguish if service was restarted, not stopped and started

Tags: systemd, services, systemctl, journalctl

Is there a way to check if a service was restarted? When performing a `systemctl restart myunit.service` or `systemctl --user restart myunit.service`, the logs only show that my unit was stopped and then started again. I need to capture when a service was **restarted** not stopped and then started again.

Also I cannot use time between stop and restart as a solution. The service some times does not stop right away. Timeout settings are built into the unit to `kill -9` the service if it takes longer than 10 seconds.

Need a way to tell if a user performed a `restart`, not a `stop` then `start` very quickly.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

`journalctl -o verbose` will contain a `JOB_TYPE` field that is set to `restart`. I can't find that field in the documentation of systemd, but https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/managing_systems_using_the_rhel_8_web_console/reviewing-logs_system-management-using-the-rhel-8-web-console mentions it:

> Filter all log messages identified by 'systemd' that happened since October 22, 2020 midnight and journal field 'JOB_TYPE' is either 'start' or 'restart.

Example entries from `journalctl -u irqbalance -o verbose` after `systemctl restart irqbalance`:

```
    JOB_TYPE=stop
    JOB_ID=3667
    INVOCATION_ID=14f864c9297247f286c8e7e07a09c40e
    UNIT=irqbalance.service
    MESSAGE=Stopping irqbalance daemon...
Mon 2022-03-14 20:26:45.263497 CET [...]
    UNIT=irqbalance.service
    JOB_TYPE=restart
    JOB_ID=3667
    MESSAGE=Stopped irqbalance daemon.
Mon 2022-03-14 20:26:45.264912 CET [...]
   JOB_TYPE=start
   JOB_RESULT=done
   UNIT=irqbalance.service
   JOB_ID=3667
```

As said above, this doesn't seem to be documented, but restarting a unit will generate these entries all tagged with the same `JOB_ID`. Manually `stop`ping and `start`ing the unit will instead only generate the `stop` and `start` entries with different `JOB_ID`s.